# PL/SQL does not print to console (in SQLDeveloper)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am writing PL/SQL trigger (INSTEAD OF type). I am trying to print to console in trigger, but it is not visible.

Script looks like this:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MYTRIGG
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON MYTABLE 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    --My varables...
BEGIN
    --Some statements

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error! Deptno does not exist!');

    --Rest of script
END;
```

I have been searching through the stack and nothing works.
I have SET SERVEROUTPUT ON and I also tried to open View -> Dbms Output

Script compiles and works as expected but does not print to console.

Comment: Turn serveroutput on and run an insert statement.

Comment: As I mentioned in description it is turned on. Insert works correctly, but it does not print to console.

Comment: it's VERY important you share EXACTLY what you're doing. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is misleading.

You can't have a INSTEAD OF trigger on a table.

Here's some working code.

```
drop table mytable;
drop view mytable_view;
create table mytable (a integer);
create view mytable_view as select * from mytable;

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MYTRIGG
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON MYTABLE_view 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
x integer;

BEGIN
    --Some statements

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error! Deptno does not exist!');


    --Rest of script
END;
/

insert into mytable_view values (1);

commit;
```

And if I run that as a script in SQL Developer -

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works. You are right, I do not do it on a table, but a view. It works when I run it as a script, not separately.

Comment: @DamDev we're assuming you know to use exceptions to deliver messages to your application/user and not dbms_output...